# Is it possible to use async + await inside describe?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs

I am trying to run something like

```
describe('REGISTRATION', async () => {
    const response = await axios.post(url, params);
});
```

I have code which works like this below

```
describe('REGISTRATION', () => {
    // success registration, check expected fields
    test('SUCCESS', async () => {
        const response = await axios.post(url, params);

        const { status, statusText } = response;
        expect(status).toBe(200);
        expect(statusText).toBe('OK');

        const { jwt, user } = response.data;
        expect(typeof(jwt)).toBe('string');

        expect(user).toEqual({
            id: expect.any(Number),
            username: expect.any(String),
            email: expect.stringMatching(emailRegExp),
        });
    });
});
```

this works but then when there's an error I do not get detail of which gives me error.
I would get something like

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
expect(user).toEqual({.......
```

so why I wanted to use `async` for `describe` is because I want to do something like

```
describe('REGISTRATION', async () => {
    const response = await axios.post(url, params);

    const { status, statusText } = response;
    const { jwt, user } = response.data;

    test('id', () => {
        expect(Number.isInteger(user.id)).toBe(true);
    });

    test('username', () => {
        expect(typeof(user.username)).toBe('string');
    });

    test('email', () => {
        expect(user.email).toEqual(expect.stringMatching(emailRegExp));
    });
});
```

so I would be able to know each the error in details while testing.

Does anyone have any idea how this would work or I am thinking too much that there is another way of doing this?

Comment: No, but you could do it in a beforeEach.

Comment: where do you want to do your error handling? inside `describe` or outside of it?? I don't mean validating

Comment: @fubar I am kinda confused, what do you mean by this?

Comment: What I was referring to is that an unhanded exception inside a Promise callback will result in the Promise being rejected. Which means that if something returns a Promise and you throw an error you can catch it with `try{ let x = await somethingAsync() } catch(err){ ... }`  This will give you the option to handle the errors on different levels. Alternative way of catching errors: `somethingAsync().catch(err => { .... })`

Comment: @fubar I got what you mean now, but that wouldn't work too or think you are able to write down an answer with full code sample or a fiddle?  Doing try catch this way will still show the same full `receive, expected` instead of one by one

Answer (score 0):

Try to use async on "it" ( and try to read this post https://staxmanade.com/2015/11/testing-asyncronous-code-with-mochajs-and-es7-async-await/ ) :

```
describe("REGISTRATION" , () => {
    it("Using an async method with async/await!", async function() {
            var result = await somethingAsync();
            expect(result).to.equal(something);                    
    });
});
```

See also https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code ( there is an async await  example )

Comment: You don't need to use both `async` and `done`. Mocha supports `Promises` out of the box so you can just return a `Promise` from the `it` callback. `async`-marked functions always return a `Promise`.

Comment: isn't this how I said my working code looks like?  which doesn't show each error in detail if there is error

Answer (score 0):

So here I have a working example that I think at least answers your question of how to see details of an async call.

So first the jesting.js file so you can see that im only returning Promises

```
const jesting = (()=>{
    function sum(a, b){
        return new Promise( (resolve)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                resolve(a+b)
            },2000)
        })
    }

    function sub(a, b){
        return new Promise( (resolve,reject)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                resolve(a-b)
            },2000)
        })
    }

    return {
        sum: sum,
        sub: sub
    }

})();

module.exports = jesting;
```

Now the jesting.test.js

```
const jesting = require('./jesting.js');

describe("STUFF", () => {

    const standByMe = jesting.sum(3, 3)

    test('a plus b is x', async () => {
        expect(await standByMe).toBe(6);
    })

    test('a plus b is x', async () => {
        expect(await standByMe).toBe(7);
    })

    test('a minus b is x', async () => {
        expect(await jesting.sub(7, 2).then(res => { return res - 2 })).toBe(3);
    })
})
```

now what happens??

So the describe will be executed at the start and `standByMe` will be set to contain a Promise that will resolve to 6 after 2 seconds, also `sub()` will return a promise that resolves after 2 seconds to 5 BUT we want 3 so we cheat :P

Notice that both a+b test `await` the same Promise which would in your case be just the one. As you can see with sub you can also manipulate the response after receiving it. What also works is `const standByMe = jesting.sum(3, 3).then(res=>{return res+1})` which would return the test for 7 to be successful

**Results**

[image: Results]

Oh and `async` on the callback of `describe` is not supported so to answer your primary question => NO, but in test yes

[image]

Comment: really thanks for the answer and demo.  I know what you mean by this but if I am using api call then I have to call api in each `test` which I do not want and I figured, there's something called `mocks` which is used to mock up api calls which I am still trying to figure out how to do :(

Comment: No, you would call the API once with `const apiCall = axios.post(url, params)`, you can await the same Promise multiple times without a new call. AKA deferred Promises.